# extends in java

Tags: java

i have make simple java program to find volume.first i have use extends then it will run but after without extends it will not run. can we also run same program without extends?

Comment: Could you show us the program?

Comment: Or better still, an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html), combined with a description (e.g. copy/pasted exceptions) of what 'will not run' means.  Also to the OP.  If *you* cannot be bothered helping your reader by adding a single upper case letter at the start of each sentence, why should *we* bother wading through that dross and trying to help you?

Answer (score 3):

You say you're using "extends" I presume you mean in the context of "extending a class" which is inheritance in Java. "Extending" the parent class allows your code to interact with the code you've been provided with and so is essential

Comment: Yes, this is inheritence in Java. You might be able to run BoxDemo directly without extending it, but it most likely holds significant code essential to help simplify your learning at this point.